# TraditionalForm with function names non-italic

Tags: formatting

I'm almost certain that there is no (simple) way to achieve this as a user, but I'll ask anyway: What has always bothered the heck out of me is that Mathematica's TraditionalForm just doesn't look quite right, and does not follow some of the widespread traditions for mathematical typesetting. I'm not even talking about the poor spacing of objects overall; Mathematica just isn't TeX/LaTeX, and there's probably no hope it ever will be, even though in principle this should be possible, but I digress...

What I have in mind here is the time-honored law that says that names of functions should *not* be italicized (which is why LaTeX provides things like \sin, \cos, \tan, etc., etc.). Mathematica and its frontend know exactly what objetcs are defined as functions, so it should be able to follow tradition and print function names in upright fonts.

Is there any way for the user to achieve this? Is there any way to get the powers that be at Mathematica do this for us?

Comment: I don't see this if I evaluate `TraditionalForm[3 Sin[x] + 2 Cos[2 x]]`.  I have "sin" and "cos" in a Roman font.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: Did the OP simply pick a poor example?  Trig functions are converted to lowercase roman font in traditional form, but this is not the case generically:  `TraditionalForm[3 f[x]+2 g[x] ]` has italicized `f` and `g`.  Perhaps the OP is asking that for anything of the form `h_[ ___ ]`, `h` be printed in non-italicized font? @m_goldberg

Comment: @jjc385. See my answer

Comment: Pirx, please edit your question to include some images of what you are describing, as well as the code used to produce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is traditional in math notation to italicize the names of functions when they are a single letter and to display them non-italicized when multi-letter. Mathematica follows this convention with user-defined functions or functional forms when displaying them in traditional form.

For example

```
f[x] + func[x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: result]

One may use [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics.html) to control this behavior:

```
noitalic = Style[#, SingleLetterItalics -> False]&;

noitalic[f][x] + func[x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't realized single letter functions were italicized by convention.  +1